# Adding "Block Selection" mode to custom editor in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I created my own editor and Extended the `TextEditor`.
When I open a file with the `TextEditor` I have the option to switch to Block selection mode. But the functionality is missing when using my own editor. I guess I have to add the command in my `plugin.xml` somehow.
I am currently searching within the eclipse-code to finde where they add the Menu to the toolbar. But can't find it.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is declared in the `org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor` plugin.

The command id for the toggle block selection command is `org.eclipse.ui.edit.text.toggleBlockSelectionMode`

The action is defined using the old style `org.eclipse.ui.actionSets` extension point:

```xml
<action
      allowLabelUpdate="true"
      definitionId="org.eclipse.ui.edit.text.toggleBlockSelectionMode"
      disabledIcon="$nl$/icons/full/dtool16/block_selection_mode.gif"
      helpContextId="org.eclipse.ui.block_selection_mode_action_context"
      icon="$nl$/icons/full/etool16/block_selection_mode.gif"
      id="org.eclipse.ui.edit.text.toggleBlockSelectionMode"
      label="%toggleBlockSelectionMode.label"
      retarget="true"
      style="toggle"
      toolbarPath="Normal/Presentation"
      tooltip="%toggleBlockSelectionMode.tooltip">
</action>
```

The action id in the text editor is `ITextEditorActionConstants.BLOCK_SELECTION_MODE`. The action is created in `org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor` in the `createActions` method.

Answer (score 1):

for how to add the "Block Selection" button into your eclipse toolbar :

goto Window--Customize prespective---
in new came out window, 
goto table "Command group avaiable" , select " editor presentation "
then goto table "Tool Bar visiability", select " editor presentation "
click OK button.